# Clique and PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity, enumeration

I was wondering how I could go about creating an algorithm that gets all the cliques in a graph in PSPACE

So far, based on some of the readings I've done, I am considering to use bit-strings (that have a length equal to the number of vertices in the graph). Then, for every possible subset of the vertices, a turing machine writes bit-strings in order and checks if the subset is a clique. On the side there will also be a counter that counts the number of cliques

This is where I am stuck so far. Can anyone help me improve my solution (or tell me whats wrong with it)? Thanks very much

Comment: Your solution seems fine. What more need you do?

Comment: Ah ok great, I wasn't quite sure if this was fine or not because this was my first time tackling a PSPACE problem. I wanted to make sure that I was capturing each clique in PSPACE. Thank you!

Comment: why do you think it might not be in PSpace? try working from the defn